# do log-out from a selected session id from a View in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

I don't know if the titles says what i'm looking for. 
Basically i got a table that shows current logged-in sessions. I'd like to be able to change their status and log them out. This is the JSTL code:

```
<div id="users_table_div">
                <table id="box-table" style="width: 690px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>USER NAME</th>
                        <th>LAST ACTIVITY</th>
                        <th>LOGIN STATUS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <c:forEach var="userDetail" items="${userSessionData}">
                      <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.ip}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.username}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.lastActivity}"/></td>
                        <td><a href="logoutUser(<c:out value='${userDetail.sessionId}'/>)"><img src="images/sign-out.png" /></a></td>
                      </tr>
                   </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Currently i've set a javascript function in the sessionId, but there might be another way to log out a selected user by its sessionId using spring security MVC.

So from the controller, i get different session data from all the users.
IP, Username, LastActivity and their SessionId (to log them out)

Is there a nice way to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been already resolved.

Just in case other is under the same issue:

I just made another @RequestMapping in the Controller with the sessionId passed from the view as the following:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/endsession?sessionId=${userDetail.sessionId}' />">
```

Then in the Controller the code was very simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/endsession", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String endSession(String sessionId, Principal principal) {
    logger.info("Removing sessionID = " + sessionId);       
    sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId).expireNow();

    return "activeusers";
}
```

And taraam :D

Hope it helps to others as well.